# How to avoid Safari favicon.ico error for local HTML files

Tags: html, safari, favicon

When I load a local HTML file in Safari, I always get the same favicon error which I cannot find any way to avoid:

```
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.  file:///favicon.ico
```

Putting a valid 'favicon.ico' file in the same folder as my HTML file does not fix the error.  And no matter what path I specify in the header for the icon, it always gives the same error as if my path specification has no effect.  I've tried relative paths, absolute paths, every combination I can think of, but nothing ever changes the error.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

To be clear, I don't care if it actually loads the favicon file, I'm just trying to find any way possible to avoid the error in the console log.  I've read through many Stackoverflow threads about similar topics, but I haven't been able to find any useful solutions.

Here are some other proposed solutions did not work for me (I'm currently on Safari 16.5.1):

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">

<link rel="icon" href="data:,">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
```

Comment: Realize that a relative path `/path/to/file` would be relative to the root of your storage drive, not the HTML folder

Comment: That's the path I used.  The favicon.ico file is already in the root of the HTML folder, which is where I would expect a browser to automatically look when loading a local HTML file since it obviously makes no sense to put the favicon in the root of my local hard drive.

Comment: A browser uses the path given. It doesn't know what folder on your hard drive is *your* "root" website folder. A relative path that starts with a forward slash `/` is relative to the root as far up as it can go. On the web, the server prevents access above the "root" folder, typically something like "public_html". Unless you have software to do the same on your computer (such as [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/)), the root folder is the base directory of the drive.

Comment: I already tried specifying a path to the file from the root of my hard drive and it doesn't work in Safari, although it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: It could be a security feature (but the browser should be able to differentiate between being on an online website and being offline on your computer.) Browsers might require different syntax, such as `file://C:/path` or just `C:/`path, or even `C:\path\to\file` with backslashes. Just some ideas without taking the time to research browser intricacies myself. A related question was asked a day after this one: [C drive file path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76839771/21849374)

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so the path shouldn't be complicated.  I've tried everything I can think of, but nothing ever seems to affect where Safari actually looks for the local file.  It always says that it can't find "file:///favicon.ico" no matter what local path I give.  I did find that it's possible to eliminate the error by providing a link to a remote site that has a favicon.   Not a great solution, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered a **3 workarounds** for this issue.

**First Method**

This method uses Safari's Inspector to **suppress the error**. Essentially you'll be instructing Safari's Web Inspector to block the request for the `file:///favicon.ico`

To do this:

1. Empty your browser cache using `⌘⌥E` (Command+Option+E)
2. Force the page to Reload using `⌘⌥R` (Command+Option+R)
3. Open the Web Inspector using `⌘⌥I` (Command+Option+I)
4. The Web Inspector indicates an error with a red stop sign with an × in it
5. Click on the **Sources** tab
6. The problem `favicon.ico` file will be shown in the file list on the left-hand side
7. Right-click the file and select **Block Request URL**
8. Reload the page, the favicon.ico file will still appear in the list with a blocked resource icon next to it but the error will be gone;  the **Console** tab will show a message "Web Inspector blocked file:///favicon.ico from loading"

This will persist through page reloads until you remove the block by navigating to the file again in the Sources tab, right-clicking and selecting **Delete Local Override**

**Second Method**

Safari seems to be hard-coded to look for `favicon.ico` at the root of the file system (Safari's Inspector reports a 404 for `file///favicon.ico`). Sadly in macOS we users don't have control over this part of our computer. Apple has provided a way to create things in `/` indirectly, and this is how the workaround is implemented.

Despite not being able to create files at `/` we can make what are referred to as *synthetic firmlinks* to things located in parts of the file system we *can* control. Essentially a *synthetic firmlink* is another kind of *alias* or *symlink* that has some special properties. You make them by listing the target and a file path in a `sythetic.conf` file.

This is how to implement this workaround. This instruction uses Terminal. It looks long and involved but it really isn't. If you think you are a Terminal novice, you are gonna be fine.

1. Make a favicon.ico file in a reasonable place that you can control. For me I put on in my user folder in a Development folder I frequently use (`/Users/myusername/Development/safari-favicon-workaround/favicon.ico`)
2. Open a Terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/synthetic.conf` this will open a Text editor in the Terminal.
3. Type the password you use to login to your Mac. This ensures you are permitted to do what we're doing here.
4. Type `favicon.ico {TAB} Users/myusername/Development/safari-favicon-workaround/favicon.ico`; **the TAB is really important. Type it with the Tab key**. *Do not use spaces*. If you make this file with a GUI or IDE editor, make sure that when you save the file, it saves with the tab character and doesn't convert tabs to spaces. Nano saves the file with the tab character intact.
5. Type `^O` (Control key and letter oh)
6. Hit `Return` Key
7. Type `^X` (Control key and letter ex)
8. Update the file we made to ensure correct permissions are set on it with these two commands: `sudo chown root:wheel /etc/synthetic.conf` then `sudo chmod 0644 /etc/synthetic.conf`; you might need to enter your login password again for these
9. Double-check that the permissions are correct by typing `ls -l /etc/synthetic.conf` you want to be sure the listing has `-rw-r--r--` and `root  wheel` in it.
10. Restart your Mac
11. Reload the offending webpage and you shouldn't see the error

**Third Method**

In my testing, viewing my webpage using a **local web server** ensured the favicon in my HTML was being used, and that Safari never went looking for the one it thinks should be at `/`. In this scenario, you'll always want to run the server and view your pages this way so you don't see the error.

There are several ways to do this on your Mac, including starting the built-in Apache web server. **I didn't test this**, but my understanding is that the files that will be served must exist in your home folder in Sites `~/Sites` (`/Users/youruser/Sites`). You will need to search for how to do this (maybe [here](https://superuser.com/questions/225346/how-do-i-setup-a-localhost-using-the-sites-folder-on-my-mac#566617) )?

Another way to run a server easily without a lot of hassle is to start a Python 3 server in the directory where you are working. There is a chance that Python 3 is not the default Python version on your Mac, but also a good chance that Python 3 is installed.

Again we'll use Terminal to do this.

1. Navigate to the place your web page is. `cd path/to/my/project`
2. Type `python3 -m http.server`
3. Assuming Python 3 is available and it doesn't return an error, open your browser and navigate to `http://localhost:8000/name-of-file`
4. You should not see the error in the Inspector.
   You can run the web server as long as you want, and to quit it press `^C` (Control and C)

I hope this  information is useful for anybody looking around for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Both 2'nd and 3'rd methods worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found that it's possible to get rid of the error by providing a link to a remote `favicon.ico` file.  Not a great solution, but it works as long as you're online.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://myhomepage.com/favicon.ico">
```

I never could find any way to get Safari to load a local favicon.ico file.  It always seems to load from the local root ("file:///favicon.ico") no matter what path you provide.  Maybe if I placed the file at the root of my hard drive it would work, but MacOS doesn't let you put things there.

Comment: Open the file in the browser (from Finder / File Explorer) and copy the path in the address bar.

Comment: That's the path I was using.  I tried what you said to make sure there wasn't some subtle difference I was missing, but it still didn't work.  It seems like a bug in Safari.