# C drive file path in HTML

Tags: html, image, path

I am newbie of using HTML.
I want to **show image located at "C:\Users\Jas mine\folder\landscape.jpg"** in HTML.
I tried all the previous posted question related to image not display while using C drive path. But those answers did not work for me.
I tried the below code and the image does not display. Can you suggest which path of code is wrong?

Moreover, how to **give file path if there is space in the folder name**?

Lastly, how to write code if I want to **display image in vertically instead of horizontally**. I did add `white-space: nowrap` but the result keeps showing in horizonal order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #images{white-space: nowrap;
                display: -moz-box;
                -moz-box-orient: veritcal;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="file:///C:\Users\Jas mine\landscape.jpg" alt="file:///C:\Users\landscape.jpg">
        <img src="file:///C:/Users/Jas mine/landscape.jpg" alt="file:///C:/Users/landscape.jpg">
        <img src="file:///C:\Users\Jas mine\landscape.jpg"\ alt="file:///C:\Users\landscape.jpg\">
        <img src="file:///C:/Users/Jas mine/landscape.jpg"\ alt="file:///C:/Users/landscape.jpg\">
        <img src="file:///C:\Users\Jas mine\landscape.jpg" alt="file:///C:\Users\landscape.jpgend\"\>
        <img src="file:///C:/Users/Jas mine/landscape.jpg" alt="file:///C:/Users/landscape.jpgend\"\>

        <img src="http:\\localhost\Jas mine\landscape.jpg" alt="http:\\localhost\landscape.jpg">
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the result here all the images are not displayed. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLUjq.png)

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="C:\Users\Jas mine\landscape.jpg">`?

Answer (score 0):

When using file paths in HTML, you need to use forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes (). Additionally, when there are spaces in the folder name, you should enclose the entire path in double quotes to avoid issues with parsing. For example:

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/Jas mine/landscape.jpg" alt="landscape">
```

Comment: Please see my second code of `<img src="file:///C:/Users/Jas mine/landscape.jpg" alt="file:///C:/Users/landscape.jpg">` The same as what you suggest. Please refer to my result. I don't get the image.

Comment: try ./landscap.jpg or keep img in same working folder

Comment: using ./landscape.jpg shows the image. But may I know how to define the path using C drive?

Comment: C:/path/to/your/file.txt